# Why do I have updates for Dolphin and Konqueror while I'm using only Unity?

Tags: unity, kde, desktop-environments

I don't remember downloading a different desktop management environment (DM), so I'm using only Unity.

Why do I have updates for Dolphin (A KDE file manager) and Konqueror (A KDE web browser) ?

I'm mean why do I have them installed in the first place ?

**EDIT**

The answers suggest that I may have downloaded tools with KDE dependencies. If that's true, why would this include main applications such as text-editors and web browsers in the updates ?

This is the output of some of the suggested commands to investigate:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep kde
kde-baseapps-bin                install
kde-baseapps-data               install
kde-l10n-engb                   install
kde-runtime                 install
kde-runtime-data                install
kdelibs-bin                 install
kdelibs5-data                   install
kdelibs5-plugins                install
libkde3support4                 install
libkdeclarative5                install
libkdecore5                 install
libkdesu5                   install
libkdeui5                   install
libkdewebkit5                   install


$ apt-cache rdepends kde
<kde>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you installed on your Ubuntu system that requires KDE libraries ??  Not all programs and games use gtk/gnome and will quickly pull in the relevant kde libraries needed to work...

Comment: Is there a way to trace that ?

Comment: "dpkg --get-selections | grep kde" to find packages which have "kde" in their name ("grep dolphin" accordingly etc.). Then "apt-cache rdepends ***" to find the reverse dependencies of a package (what depends on it).

Comment: Please check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

Some of your unity package may use KDE dependencies.
You can check from your console what package use your KDE dependencies with :

```
 apt-cache rdepends {package}
```

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: Have you tried to check which application required the KDE dependencies as requested in both answer ?

Comment: Like `apt-cache rdepends kde` ? I ran this command and put the output in my question.

Answer (score 0):

This happens quite often when you install a program that requires KDE libraries. For example, when you install K3b, the popular disk burning software, it requires all this:

```
k3b
Reverse Depends:
  kmediafactory
  dvd95
 |uck
  quodlibet-plugins
  kubuntu-full
  kubuntu-desktop
  k3b-i18n
  k3b-dbg
  juk
 |aptoncd
```

as you can see, it requires several kubuntu libraries, and when you use the application it uses those programs, as that is what it was written to interact with.

Thus, when an update occurs, those programs installed as dependencies are also updated.

Comment: Is it possible that a web browser or a text editor application be treated as a dependency ?!

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana Well, if they were installed by another program, they are considered a dependency, as they are needed by that program. Thus, if Konquerer was installed by another program its going to be updated. Also, what application was it that you installed?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'm trying to figure out